# pdfjam: Merging multiple pdfs into one page

Tags: pdf

I have multiple pdfs that I want to merge. Suppose I have 5 PDFs (4 of the same dimension of 1x5cm, and 1 of a dimension of 1.5x5cm). How can I merge all of these PDFs together *without pdfjam resizing the latter figure*?

I wish to keep the paper size 6.5x5cm, just want to pdfs to be side by side, and don't wish to add any extra margins between each pdf.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow why you have tagged this with 'Ghostscript' yet your question relates to 'pdfjam' ?

Comment: StackOverflow says I need 1,500 rep points to tag pdfjam.

Comment: That is (I think) because there **is** no pdfjam tag, and you would have to create one, which needs reputation. Anyway, its not a Ghostscript question, so I've removed the tag.

Comment: I think that's the case too. Have you come across any tools that can merge pdfs together, side-by-side with different dimensions?

Comment: You could use Ghostscript to do it (though it snot going to be 'merging' and you would need to be able to do some PostScript programming.